# Как указать путь сохранения создаваемого zip-архива? (модули "zipfile" и "os")

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import zipfile
import os

os.chdir('D:\\py_project_1\\zip_demo')

>>> os.listdir()
['snippets.txt', 'test.txt', 'thumbnail.jpg']

zipFile = zipfile.ZipFile('create.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
zipFile.write('thumbnail.jpg')
zipFile.close()
```

Всем привет. Вот простенький код создания zip-архива с помощью встроенных модулей 'zipfile' и 'os'.
Можно ли с помощью тех же модулей (или иных, встроенных в Python) указать куда сохранять создаваемый zip-архив? И если да, то как это сделать?

Comment: Вместо create.zip написать нужный путь, очевидно

Comment: Благодарю за подсказку.